# Haskell State Monad and Binary not outputting everything

Tags: haskell, monads, state-monad

I've been playing around with some simple binary encoding and it seemed to be working correctly for the most part, up until I added the state monad. The plan was to use the state to keep a lookup table of what I have written to the bytestring so far, and then write out offsets to previous instances of strings rather than duplicate them.

I got everything type checked and running, but then I noticed that it was only writing out the final instruction in the chain. I changed to using the Control.Monad.State.Strict but that made no difference, so I suspect I'm making a fundamental error somewhere else, but I'm not sure where - I've trimmed the code down to the basic functionality. Also, is there a more idiomatic way of doing this?

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}


import           Control.Applicative
import qualified Control.Monad.State.Strict as S
import           Data.Binary.Put
import qualified Data.ByteString            as BS
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy       as BL

data SState = SState {
   wsPosition :: Int
   -- plus whatever else
}

initialState = SState 0
type StatePut = S.State SState Put

class StateBinary a where
   sput :: a -> StatePut

incPos :: Int -> S.State SState ()
incPos amnt = do
   (SState p) <- S.get
   S.put $ SState (p + amnt)

writeSized :: Int -> (a -> Put) -> a -> StatePut
writeSized n f x = do
                    incPos n
                    return (f x)

writeInt32 :: Int -> StatePut
writeInt32 = writeSized 32 putWord32be . fromIntegral

writeBS :: BS.ByteString -> StatePut
writeBS b = writeSized (BS.length b) putByteString b

data SomeData = SomeData {
    sdName :: BS.ByteString
  , sdAge  :: Int
  , sdN    :: Int
} deriving (Show, Eq)

instance StateBinary SomeData where
    sput (SomeData nm a n) = do
           writeBS nm
           writeInt32 a
           writeInt32 n

testData = SomeData "TestName" 30 100

runSPut :: StateBinary a => a -> BL.ByteString
runSPut a = runPut $ S.evalState (sput a) initialState

-- runSPut testData returns "\NUL\NUL\NULd"
```

Comment: What is `writeSized` and where should it be imported from?  This code does not compile for me.

Comment: Sorry, I was copy-pasting in batches and skipped it by accident - added it in now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `writeSized` is not actually writing to the bytestring. `return` only wraps the `Put` computation into the state monad without actually running it. There might be smarter ways to solve it, but the obvious one would be taking advantage of the fact that `Put` (actually [`PutM`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/binary-0.7.1.0/docs/Data-Binary.html#t%3aPut)) is a monad and using monad transformers to compose it with the state monad:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}


import           Control.Applicative
import qualified Control.Monad.State.Strict as S
import           Data.Binary.Put
import qualified Data.ByteString            as BS
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy       as BL

data SState = SState {
   wsPosition :: Int
   -- plus whatever else
}

initialState = SState 0
-- S.StateT SState PutM is a composed monad, with a state layer above PutM.
type StatePut = S.StateT SState PutM ()

class StateBinary a where
   sput :: a -> StatePut

incPos :: Int -> StatePut
incPos amnt = do
   (SState p) <- S.get
   S.put $ SState (p + amnt)

writeSized :: Int -> (a -> Put) -> a -> StatePut
writeSized n f x = do
                    incPos n
                    -- lift runs a computation in the underlying monad.
                    S.lift (f x)

writeInt32 :: Int -> StatePut
writeInt32 = writeSized 32 putWord32be . fromIntegral

writeBS :: BS.ByteString -> StatePut
writeBS b = writeSized (BS.length b) putByteString b

data SomeData = SomeData {
    sdName :: BS.ByteString
  , sdAge  :: Int
  , sdN    :: Int
} deriving (Show, Eq)

instance StateBinary SomeData where
    sput (SomeData nm a n) = do
           writeBS nm
           writeInt32 a
           writeInt32 n

testData = SomeData "TestName" 30 100

runSPut :: StateBinary a => a -> BL.ByteString
runSPut a = runPut $ S.evalStateT (sput a) initialState

-- *Main> runSPut testData
-- "TestName\NUL\NUL\NUL\RS\NUL\NUL\NULd"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a bytestring `Builder` (edit: now using the one from `binary` instead of from `bytestring`):

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import           Data.Monoid
import qualified Data.Binary                as B
import qualified Data.Binary.Builder        as BU
import qualified Data.ByteString            as BS
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy       as BL

data SomeData = SomeData {
    sdName :: BS.ByteString
  , sdAge  :: Int
  , sdN    :: Int
} deriving (Show, Eq)

testData :: SomeData
testData  = SomeData "TestName" 30 100

renderData :: SomeData -> BU.Builder
renderData (SomeData n a i) = mconcat $
  BU.fromByteString n : map (BU.fromLazyByteString . B.encode) [a,i]

test :: BL.ByteString
test = BU.toLazyByteString . renderData $ testData
```

The idea is that the introduction (`BU.fromX`) and appending operations are O(1), so you only pay at the end when you convert back to a `ByteString`.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look at implementing this along with the State code above. Am I right in saying that for this to work I would need Binary instance for each field in my datatype, in order for the B.encode call to work?

Comment: You just need a way to turn your fields into `Builder`s.  `Data.Binary` gives you ways to do this for `ByteString`s, `Word`s, and `Char`s.  Using `encode` is simply a convenience because it hides the details of `Int` serialization (which is very easy to get wrong -- you have a potential truncation error on 64-bit machines), but you could use `putWordX . fromIntegral` instead as you did originally.

Comment: Also, making `Binary` instances is [very easy](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/binary-0.7.1.0/docs/Data-Binary.html#g:3).

Comment: Cool, I'll give this a shot. I'm not doing anything particularly performance intensive but I'd rather get in the habit of doing things properly while I'm still learning!